# How to revert redirect command in zf2

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

I'm looking proper way to revert any given redirect command in ZF2 controller

For example in one of my function i use - $this->redirect()->toRoute('my/desire/path/to/redirect');
But after getting result I want to cancel that command and show something else to my user.

Here is my code to illustrate more precisely -

considering following method inside controller that will retrieve data for one id

```
public function getMyData(){
    $idX = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    $rtrn=$this->myTableGateway->getData($idX);
    if($rtrn!==false){
        $mnfctr['myData']=$rtrn;
        $mnfctr['readMode']='yes';
        return $mnfctr;
    }else return $this->redirect()->toRoute('product-loader/sub-categories', array('cid'=>$this->mcep->id));
}
```

now in a real action inside controller

```
public function readAction(){
    $data=$this->getMyData();
    if($data instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response) return $data;
    # do rest of the staff of read action
}
public function deleteAction(){
    $data=$this->getMyData();
    if($data instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response) return $data;
    # do rest of the staff of delete action
}
```

now i want to show a logo of my company through the same controller
problem is if i simply redirect the logo should not draw properly
so i design my image action method as follows

```
public function logoAction(){
    $logoFlName='Unknown Company';
    $data=$this->getMyData();
    #echo '$mnfctr: '.get_class($mnfctr); exit();
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    if($mnfctr instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response){
        # in this situation i need to cancel my previous response command
        $logoFlName='Invalid Company';
        if($response->isRedirect()){
            $this->flashMessenger()->clearCurrentMessages();
            $response->getHeaders()->clearHeaders();
            $response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_200);
        }
    }elseif(is_array($data) && array_key_exists('myData', $data) && $data['myData'] instanceof MyData){
        # code to draw the real logo
        $logoFlName='Logo of XYZ Company';
    }else{ /* something wrong and can't be happen. but we really can't find logo */ }
    $newImage=PLImageHelper::getLogoFromString($string2draw__not_found_image__or__logo);
    $response->setContent($newImage->get('png'));
    $response->getHeaders()
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'image/png')
        ->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'filename="'.$logoFlName.'.png"')
        #->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', mb_strlen($imageContent))
        ;
    return $response;
}
```

I know there has a lot of way, suppose its possible to redirect to a real no-image-found.png file to show. but i want it programmatically

Comment: You should update the question with your code as it is difficult to answer without it. What I can say is that redirecting using the plugin changes response status code and then returning it will then perform the redirect. So 'cancelling that command' would mean removing the headers; although it would  really make more sense doing whatever it is you need to do and only calling the redirect plugin when you actually need to perform the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best possible way I get -

```
$response = $this->getResponse();
if($response->isRedirect()){
    $response->getHeaders()->clearHeaders();
    $response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_200);
}
```

Is there any other way to do it. I mean more efficient way that I can use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect the user to where the request is coming from you can use the following:

```
/** @var \Zend\Http\Request $request */
$request = $this->getRequest()
return $this->redirect()->toUrl($request->getHeaders()->get('referer')->getUri());
```

`getUri()` will return an url, for example: `http://http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27318052/edit`. Hope this helps.

Comment: here i don't want to know the way to redirect. my concern is to cancel my previous redirect command and send browser that my script is ok with current request and can serve data.

Comment: There is no way to cancel a redirect as it is like an html A element, once you click it it will open that url. In that case you shouldn't redirect if you are not certain or you have to show some code since its hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. I think you are misunderstanding the idea of the redirect plugin.

Comment: i add some more details of my problem for you, hope it help to understand.

Comment: I still have no clue what you are trying to achieve with the redirect plugin. I've got the feeling you're trying to use the redirect plugin for a purpose it isnt designed for. Just explain in plain text what the application has to do step for step, since I still have no idea what ur trying to achieve with those images etc. And please use , and . to break down ur sentences, as it is really hard to read without any. ;)

Comment: I'm looking the proper way to revert any given redirect command in ZF2 controller

Comment: @ShahadatHossainKhan like we said before maybe you shouldn't use the redirect plugin. I think you should look at the forward plugin of ZF2 instead and dispatch to your logoAction with a given parameter to handle your logic in there. Take a look at the forward plugin: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-forward

Comment: forward plugin will not consider here, cause I don't want to jump one into another. if you don't think that i didn't use redirect plugin properly. i'm agree with you. my point was not the way we using redirect plugin. my point was, how we can revert our redirect command (may be i use redirect command mistakenly)...